# Upload a photo in my app using Facebook Android API, but not shown to public

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I have integrated Facebook login in my Android app, and successfully uploaded photos to my Facebook album using the in-app login. However I wish the shared photos would be public to all of my audience, but the default is shown to the user only. What should I do for this problem?

Comment: Can you show some code on what you have done for uploading photos initially, so that it would show your research and even help others suggesting you according to that code?

Answer (score 3):

The codes are modified from the facebook sdk samples. The other problem I just found is that I can only use my own account to authorize the app (as the app administrator), my friends could not log in use their account.

```
private void postPhoto() {
    if (hasPublishPermission()) {
        Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(bitmapPath);
        Request request = Request.newUploadPhotoRequest(Session.getActiveSession(), 
                  image, new Request.Callback() {

            @Override
            public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                showPublishResult(response.getError());
                dialog.dismiss();
            }

        });
        //add progress bar here!
        showDialog(0);
        request.executeAsync();

    } else {
        pendingAction = PendingAction.POST_PHOTO;
    }
}
```